# What is the correct formula for Bond Yield?

Tags: bonds, calculation, government-bonds, yield

Taking an introductory investment course, was following up on bond yields.

I thought the yield is calculated as follows (sorry for some reason LaTex formatting doesn't work - so inserting an image):

[image]

I am so very confused with all the terms.  I was trying to unpack this [simple example](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/treasury-yield.asp)

> ...For example, if a 10-year T-note with a face value of $1,000 is auctioned off at a yield of 3%, a subsequent drop in its market value to $974.80 will cause the yield to rise to 3.3%, since the Treasury will still be making the $30 ($1,000 x .03) annual coupon payments as well as the $1,000 principal repayment...

Now if I got the formula correct, subsequent drop in market price would cause yield to increase to 3.07% not 3.3%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 3.30% yield mentioned in the example is the [*yield to maturity*](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/y/yieldtomaturity.asp) (YTM), not the *current yield*. Unlike the current yield, the yield to maturity takes into account the $25.20 income (1000 - 974.80) from buying the bond below face value.

You could use a spreadsheet's `RATE` function to calculate the YTM like this:

[image: Spreadsheet calculation of yield to maturity (YTM)]

Comment: Thanks! In this example (https://www.investopedia.com/articles/bonds/07/price_yield.asp#toc-reading-bond-quotes), they specifically mention current yield, do you know if they really mean ytm?  Because once again for 2 year bond I can't get 3.08%  I get (30/99.84) = 3.004%  If you think this should be its own question I can create one thx again.

Comment: @hba There might be a mistake in that article. The 3.08% for the 2 year bond is its YTM, not its *current yield*. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zda2W.png

Comment: the terms are so confusing - thanks for your help!